# conectarme a base de datos de una pagina php en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

quería realizar una consulta, en laravel tengo una vista, en la cual obtengo datos de la BD y en esta pagina necesito ir actualizando un tabla HTML, dependiendo de lo que elija el usuario, para poder actualizar esa tabla sin refrescar la vista, es por ello que realizo una función JS, la que toma los datos y los envía a un archivo PHP y este los procesa y envía el resultado a la vista, esto me funciona, pero antes de poder enviar esos datos desde el archivo PHP a la tabla de la vista, necesito validarlos con la BD, y esto no se como hacerlo ya que este archivo php no es un controlador.

Esta es mi funcion JS

```
var formulario = document.getElementById('form_ingreso');
var incorrecto = document.getElementById('respuesta');
var respuesta = document.getElementById('listado');

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var datos = new FormData(formulario);
datos.get('Sel_materiales');
datos.get('Txt_cantidad');

fetch('../resources/views/system/post1.php',{

 method:'POST',
 body: datos
})
 .then(res=> res.json())
 .then(data=> {
     if(data === 'error'){
         incorrecto.innerHTML =`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Debe Llenar todos los campos</div>`
     }else{
         incorrecto.innerHTML =``
         respuesta.insertRow(0).innerHTML =`
                 <tr class="small">
                     <td>1000</td>
                     ${data}
                 </tr>
         `
     }
 })
});
```

Esta mi pagina PHP (hijo)

```
<?php
$material=$_POST['Sel_materiales'];
$cantidad=$_POST['Txt_cantidad'];
if($material === '')
{
    echo json_encode('error');
}else{
    echo json_encode('<td>'.$material.'</td> <td>'.$cantidad.'</td>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Como? quieres hacer ese codigo pero en laravel???

Comment: Es decir quieres extraer información de una base de datos para enviarla a otro sistema, pero no tienes un sistema en php para extraer la información de la base de datos para enviarla a un segundo sistema en Laravel? En pocas palabras lo que necesitas es una API rest que consulte un backend en PHP desde JavaScript y envie la información a un backend en Laravel.

Pero el backend en php no lo has construido por eso quieres saber como te puedes conectar y extraer información.

¿Es eso?

Comment: BetaM  estoy trabajando en laravel y dentro de una vista llamo a esa funcion JS, por eso pongo la etiqueta de laravel, puede que la pregunta a lo mejor no este clara , pero te pido no seas tan arbitrario en cambiar las etiquetas, si saber mas del problema

Comment: @Luis Alfredo Serrano Díaz, no es a otro sistema, en laravel tengo una vista, en la cual obtengo datos de la BD y en esta pagina necesito ir actualizando un tabla HTM, dependiendo de lo que elija el usuario, para poder actualizar esa tabla sin refrescar la vista, es que realizo esa función JS, la que toma los datos y los envía a un archivo PHP y este los procesa y es en este archivo donde necesito validar los datos contra la base de datos y el resultado enviarlo a las vista, yo logro que la tabla en la vista se actualice, pero no se como validar antes esos datos que recibo en el archivo php.

Comment: Checate este crud que construí, esta hecho en PHP el backend y el front lo estoy consultando con VueJS y axios, pero al final la necesidad es la misma, no te digo que uses exactamente eso, pero te puede dar luces. https://github.com/felloz/clientes_crud

Comment: @ BetaM, listo amigo ahí modifique mi pregunta, espero haber explicado mejor mi problema, saludos y gracias

Comment: Para que tu backend reciba la información debes colocar algo similar a esto:
`$json = file_get_contents('php://input')` y luego hacer el decode al json con `$data = json_decode($json)` ya lo que te queda es con la variable `$data` acceder a los atributos y estos datos que recibes meterlos en una consulta SQL.